# nodejs pkg - property 'bin' does not exist in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

i'm using PKG to build a program using package.json. I included the "pkg" property in package.json but pkg always returns `Error! Property 'bin' does not exist in [path to package.json]`

when i add the bin property it asks for the directory for the path to bin, i tried giving it the path the .bin folder in node_modules (which does make the error go away), however the generated executable just crashes immidiatley with no error. I havent found this error anywhere else.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Setting the property `"bin"` to `"./main.js"` *(the program's entrypoint)* seems to have fixed the problem. `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./main.js",
  "bin": "./main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue transpiling TS to JS. The problem was related to the folder structure: `src/ts/main.ts` meanwhile in `package.json` the main point was `bin/main.js`, so after JS generation there was any `main.js` in `bin` folder.

Comment: Could you elaborate with text examples? As I think you have the solution to my problem!